# is there away to make widget visible in stack

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following code

```
    Stack(
     children:[
      Container(
        color:Colors.red,
        width:200,
        height: 200,
       ),
        Container(
       color:Colors.green,
       width:200,
       height: 200,
       )
     ]
    )
```

Now logically green `Container` the one who will be above the other red  `Container`

but is there away to make the red one is above the other one without to make it in the last element in the stack ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cant just have it as the last element in the stack?

Comment: thanks @DevonRay for your awesome question, i have list of widgets into stack . every widget has it's own Transform.translate widget, by user finger it be animated around . so the widget could be hidden by others widget . so i am trying to find way to give priority to current animated widget to be above others .

Comment: i tried to set the current animated widget as last element in list as your wish , but i will lost the second snapshot detect by GestureDetector . so user should 1- press to change bool then press again to have it's new detection . This is inappropriate

Comment: go to your children property and reverse it. `children: [Container(), Container()].reverse.toList()`

Comment: if you read the comments you will not hit that tip

Comment: conditional if may help but for N number of item replacing index may better, but in both case it will switch the item render position

Comment: @YeasinSheikh also will lost the current detection !

Comment: you can use Positioned widget in the stack children and you can set the dimensions of each one.

Comment: @MohammedHamdan can you share a screenshot or detail of your end goal, struggling to understand what it is you're trying to acheive.